# git push fatal failed

Tags: git, push

I somehow deleted the whole directory of my code branch. I cloned a new one. It worked fine except pushing.

```
~/workspace/wtf (mybranch)]$ git push origin  mybranch 
error: Cannot access URL [my url], return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

git pull works, though. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, read this manual [here](http://www.parallelsymmetry.com/howto/git.jsp) and notice the point about `http.receivepack`.

Answer (score 33):

I made the mistake of using https instead of ssh for a fresh copy.
I since then made modifications and commits but could not push for obvious reasons.

To recover, I simple changed the section [remote "origin"] in .git/config from

> url = https://github.com/AIFDR/riab_core.git

to

> url = git@github.com:AIFDR/riab_core.git

After that, I could push again.

Comment: No need to move to another protocol, read my answer below if you would like to push over http.

Comment: Agree with Basil, this is unnecessary, and impossible in some corporate environments that have limited access through firewalls, etc.

Comment: ...the problem is with `git-http-push failed`, I see the op is trying to set up things either over http or https, -1.

Answer (score 14):

### Faster HTTP Push with only git -  webDAV is not required

The new "smart-http" support since git 1.6.6.  The new method allows the entire pack to be transmitted at once, and not as individual files.

YOu can also use gitweb to provide browable URLs  at the same location.

Note: Because access is controlled by apache you can add any Auth requirements (htaccess or ldap, etc) to the  setup for each repository.

This answer assumes you own the remote server and want to add/fix http support.

FIRST:
Check the apache logs, its likely a permission denied/unable to locate error when apache tries to execute the git-http-backed cgi scripts.

### Adding HTTP Support to git

Just make a new git_support.conf file, and include it in apache (add include statement in httpd.conf)

```
#
#  Basic setup for git-http-backend
#

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /opt/git_repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER  #IMportant !!! This could be your problem if missing

<Directory /opt/git>  # both http_backend and gitweb should be somewhere under here
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -Includes  #Important! Lets apache execute the script!
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>

# This pattern matches git operations and passes them to http-backend
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD | \
                        info/refs | \
                        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                                 [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                                 pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                        git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
        /opt/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

# Anything not matched above goes to displayable gitweb interface
ScriptAlias /git /opt/git/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi/
```

The result is the ability to push/pull:

```
me@machine /tmp/eddies $ git pull
Already up-to-date.

me@machine /tmp/eddies $ touch changedFile

me@machine /tmp/eddies $ git add .

me@machine /tmp/eddies $ git commit -am"commiting change"
[master ca7f6ed] commiting change
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 changedFile

me@machine /tmp/eddies $ git push origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 239 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To http://mysecretdomain.com/git/eddies
   0f626a9..ca7f6ed  master -> master
```

And you can browse those changes online..
[image: gitweb provides a browsable interface]

Source:
http://repo.or.cz/w/alt-git.git?a=blob_plain;f=gitweb/README

Comment: When I run the IMPORTANT line about the user, line 7, I get `"SetEnv takes 1-2 arguments, an environment variable name and optional value to pass to CGI."` -- why?

Comment: I would guess that value is empty, so setenv only sees 0 arguments.  Because the apache uses a redirect rule it is possible REMOTE_USER is empty, so we grab the REDIRECT_RMEOTE_USER.  You should be able to make the assignment optional if RMEOTE_USER is already defined (or rather is REDIRECT user is empty). http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif

Answer (score 7):

To enable a "**git push**" over http, you have to enable WebDAV on the webserver. To do that for Apache Webserver, simply edit the configuration file:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then search for the line starting with:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Add the following line just after it:

```
Dav On
```

Make sure you have the following line also in httpd.conf uncommented:

```
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
```

After that you are ready. Restart Apache Webserver using:

```
service httpd restart
```

Also make sure to make all the git repository files on the server be writable by the pache:apache user and group using:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/your_git_repository
```

Otherwise, failing to set correct permissions will result in "PUT error: curl result=22, HTTP code=403" when performing a "git push".

Now simply do a "git push" from your client machine and all should work.

Comment: Note, if users get past this hurdle, but see an error in the apcahe logs about receive-pack   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792611/receive-pack-service-not-enabled-for-git/7150380#7150380

Comment: This will work, but DAV is *not* required, and actually performs much slower than smart-http.

Answer (score 4):

You can't push on a repository you cloned through HTTP.
You need to update the URL to either a `ssh://` or a `git://` type URL.

Comment: I used the same clone command. It worked before until I made the wrong deletion....

Comment: what do you have with `git remote -v` ?

Comment: Not entirely true. You can push back to repositories, assuming DAV is enabled.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Git since 1.6.6 supports smart http pushes and pulls using apache and git-http-backend.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the following section of your .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://git.repository.url/repo.git
```

to

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = http://username:password@git.repository.url/repo.git
```

Then try `git push origin master`.

Edit the authentication details in your config files for other repository URLs as required and push to the required branch.

Comment: Note: I used this method and it solved my issue - however I thought storing the password in the config file seemed wrong, so I left it off (hoping to be prompted for it), and was able to use it as such.

Comment: `git remote set-url origin ...` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with push operation with git-http-backend, ldap authentication config.
Finally I've found the solution and describe it [in this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/651858/git-http-backend-and-ldap-authentication-push-error-requested-url-returned-err)

Maybe it will help someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Great

i had other errors but it works!

i try to explain:

- install an ubuntu server with apache2 and webdav
- Look at http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2011/02/09/setup-a-remote-git-repository-using-http-with-push-support-and-digest-auth/ for details
- clone on client -> Perfect!
- change something....
- push -> failed
- change owner on server
- Error  "PUT error: curl result=22, HTTP code=403" has gone..
- now only says git-http-push failed
- serverlog: `Could not LOCK /path/to/www/gitproject/refs/heads/master due to a failed precondition (e.g. other locks)`
- i used the answer from `user1520409` ist works.

BUT how to hide the password from the text at the push message?

Answer (score -1):

This can also happen if you entered a wrong password.

Comment: I've never seen that: I always get `fatal: Authentication failed` first